# angular 2 observable next

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I'm trying to understand the use of observables,

everything is ok in the simple cases, but in one case I want to compress several images.

I'm using  `ng2-img-tools`

> Method to compress an image. This reduces the quality of an image down
>   until it fits a certain fileSize which is given as maxSizeInMB. Set
>   ignoreAlpha to true if you want to ignore the alpha channel for png
>   images and compress them nonetheless (not recommended - the alpha
>   channel will be lost and the resulting image might differ from the
>   original image). **Returns an observable that for every file given,
>   onNext receives either a File when everything went as planned or an
>   error Object if something went wrong**.

In my code, I'm doing the following :

```
compressImages(filesToUpload:File[]):Observable<any> {
    if (filesToUpload && filesToUpload.length > 0) {
      return this.ng2ImgToolsService.compress(filesToUpload,GlobalService.MAX_FILE_SIZE_MB).map(response =>  {
        console.log("response is");
        console.log(response)
        return response;
      });
    }
    return Observable.of("no_image").map(response =>  "no_image");

  }


this.imageService.compressImages(filesToUpload).flatMap(result => {
          console.log(result)
          return  this.http.post(...);
        }
      ).catch(UtilsService.handleError);
```

the problem is result returns only 1 file, I know i should use `result.next()` somewhere but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need `subscribe` to the function, not perform another map. When you subscribe to an observable, you're implicitly receiving the value of `onNext()` as **result**

```
this.imageService.compressImages(filesToUpload).subscribe(
    result => {
        // this contains the value of onNext()
        console.log(result)
        return     this.imageService.compressImages(filesToUpload).subscribe(
    result => {
        // this contains the value of onNext()
        console.log(result)
        return  this.http.post(...);
    }, error => {
        // error
    } this.http.post(...);
    }, error => {
        // error
    }
```

[more info on subscribing](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html)

**EDIT**

---

if you'd like to collect all item in the stream and operate on them as one list, you can use `toList()` like so:

```
this.imageService.compressImages(filesToUpload).toList().subscribe(
    result => {
        // this contains all values from the stream
        console.log(result)
        return  this.http.post(...);
    }, error => {
        // error
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do I "loop over" all the next() values ?

Comment: @DanyY is it not already looping for you? Subscribe applies the lambda function whenever something enters the stream, so the function passed would be applied for every onNext

Comment: Thank uu!! now things are finally starting to make sense, It's not happening in my case because when I receive a result I'm directly posting to the server.
But in a separate test, it's working exactly like you said.
Is there a way to wait for all of them to finish to then post to the server?

Comment: Thank you, `toList()` is giving me a compile error because the result of the function is  a ` Observable<any>` but I got the idea, I'll find the equivalent. Thanks for your time